# Return a Value from Ajax response

Tags: ajax, function

I have the following function:

```
    function ProcessFormData(formName, proItem, ctl, method)
    {
    //some operations here
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CommonControl/GenericProcess",
            data:aData,
            success: function(response){
     //return response;
    } });

var fBar=ProcessFormData(a,b,c,d)
```

How can i return response such that:
`var fBar=ProcessFormData(a,b,c,d)` return ajax's success `response`

I have tried all examples provided here to no success.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: That did not work either. That is where i started. Callback?